# SQL in rowsource needs to change when form becomes a subform

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database which contains two SQL problems in Row Source attributes.

The FindClientsNavigation form in the database was working properly until I dragged it into a navigation control on a Main form, so that FindClientsNavigation became a subform.  Now the following two problems need to be fixed:

1.) When you load the Main form, a dialog box appears asking for a parameter for the txtFilterClients text box.  txtFilterClients is used to filter client names and IDS in a listbox lstbxclients.  lstbxclients is populated by having its rowsource set to the following query:

```
SELECT c.ClientNumber, c.FullName FROM Clients AS c
WHERE (((c.FullName) Like '*' & [Forms]![Main]![FindClientsNavigation]![txtFilterClients].[Text] & '*'))
ORDER BY c.FullName;
```

You can see the error message/dialog in the following printscreen:

[image]

2.) The ***second error*** occurs when you click on the "Communication Forms" navigation tab and a dialog box appears asking for the value of ClientID, which is a property of the FindClientsNavigation form.  This second problem seems to be in the Row Source property for the qryListCommunicationForms form, whose SQL is currently:

```
CommunicationTable.CommunicationNumber, CommunicationTable.ClientNumber, CommunicationTable.DateOfCommunication, CommunicationTable.Communication, CommunicationTable.Communication, CommunicationTable.CommunicationWithNumber  
FROM CommunicationTable  
WHERE (((CommunicationTable.ClientNumber)=[Forms]![Main]![FindClientsNavigation].[ClientNumber]));
```

I am looking for solutions to both problems, and I would also appreciate some explanation of the concepts underlying the code so that I can know how to fix similar problems which may emerge elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to follow your description fully, but assuming that `FindClientsNavigation` is a subform then you need to also reference its `Form` property to be able to reference a control *within a subform*:

```
[Forms]![Main]![FindClientsNavigation].Form![txtFilterClients]
```

you also don't need to refer to the `Text` property of the `TextBox`.

**Added**: If the `RowSource` is being assigned as a string then it needs to be split into three parts, so that the textbox value will be substitied into the SQL:

```
"SELECT c.ClientNumber, c.FullName FROM Clients AS c WHERE (((c.FullName) Like '*'" &
[Forms]![FindClientsNavigation].[Form]![txtFilterClients] & "'*')) ORDER BY c.FullName;"
```

**Added**: The name of your subform control is `NavigationSubform`, `FindClientsNavigation` is the `SourceObject` for this control. So you need to use:

```
Like '*' & [Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFilterClients] & '*'
```

The exclamation (the bang operator!) references the default Collection for an object which, for a Form, is its Controls collection.

This change also needs to be made in the code-behind your form `qryListCommunicationForm`, and the `RowSource` shown in your original post.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help.  But it still does not work.  I put the new SQL in an edit to my original posting above, just in case there is some typo you can see.  Access added the brackets around [Form].  I think I entered it exactly as you suggested.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, the quotes won't work in SQL-view; as I said, this only applies if the `RowSource` is supplied as a string. When the parameter-request box appears what does it now ask for..? What is the expression that appears in it? If it doesn't include the `.[Form]` text that I added then the reference to the control is somewhere else - perhaps in the properties of the form, or subform, somewhere (or in the Parameters dialog).

Comment: You still have the quotes around that RowSource: you don't need them there.

Comment: I've added further to my answer. (And, yes, I downloaded it a few minutes ago ;) )

Comment: Hi. I don't really know of good Access tutorial sites, other than allenbrowne.com who has excellent advice and examples, or the book Access Inside Out - which covers everything ;) and is also suitable for beginners (one of the authors assures me..).

Comment: Stack overflow just allowed me to award you the bounty.  Sorry for the delay.  Thanks again for helping me.  I ended up figuring out the answer to the questions in the other posting.  It just takes a while to find the right key words, and the answers are never all in one place with vba, so there is a lot of stop and start.  By contrast, the java documentation and code base on the web is a lot more user/coder friendly.  Thank you again. +100